# How to POST & GET image using lumen laravel in API?

Tags: laravel, api, lumen

I have this database

```
return new class extends Migration
{
    /**
     * Run the migrations.
     *
     * @return void
     */
    public function up()
    {
        Schema::create('post', function (Blueprint $table) {
             $table->bigIncrements('id'); 
      $table->string('title', 100) -> nullable();
      $table->text('content', 300)-> nullable();
      $table->string('image', 100)-> nullable();
      $table->string('phone', 300)-> nullable();
      $table->string('coordinates', 300)-> nullable();
      $table->string('website', 300)-> nullable();
      $table->timestamps();
        });
    }

    /**
     * Reverse the migrations.
     *
     * @return void
     */
    public function down()
    {
        Schema::dropIfExists('post');
    }
};
```

i want to post and get the image, the only thing that i confuse is, how to get the image that i post, im already call it in my API but the result is 404, im already uploaded it on web service http://lovemonster.my.id/hospital just look & click on image section, it showing the error, this is my controller:

```
class HospitalController extends Controller
{
    public function create(Request $request)
    {
        $data = $request->all();
        $hospital = Hospital::create($data);

        return response()->json($hospital);
    }
    public function index()
    {
        $hospital = Hospital::all();
        return response()->json($hospital);
    }
}
```

and this is my model:

```
class Hospital extends Model
{
    protected $table = 'post';
    /**
     * The attributes that are mass assignable.
     *
     * @var array
     */
    protected $fillable = [
        'title','content','image', 'phone', 'coordinates', 'website'
    ];

}
```

how to get the image that i store, what the code looks like on my controller, if you know how to do it please let me know cause im new to lumen and laravel

Comment: "i want to post and get the image, the only thing that i confuse is, how to get the image that i post,"       " im already call it in my API but the result is 404" => show example code how you post the image, show example code how you get the image. Show the 404 error. Try it in Postman, same result? Only way you can resolve your 404 error is to start debugging, you can do that in your example code where you are getting your image

Comment: I post the image through postman and my server is automatically save it into /tmp folder, and when I clicked the value of "image" it show another error with 404 not found, same when i tried it on postman, it showing the error as well

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For post requests, you need to save image inside public or storage folder and add that path inside db for image.

```
class HospitalController extends Controller
{
    public function create(Request $request)
    {
        // upload image
        $filename = $this->getFileName($request->image);
        $request->image->move(base_path('public/images'), $filename);
    
        $hospital = new Hospital(request()->except('image'));
        $hospital->image = $filename;
        $hospital->save();

        return response()->json($hospital);
    }
    

    protected function getFileName($file)
    {
       return str_random(32) . '.' . $file->extension();
    }

    public function index()
    {
        $hospital = Hospital::all();
        return response()->json($hospital);
    }
}
```

Your model **Hospital.php**

```
class Hospital extends Model
{
    protected $table = 'post';
    /**
     * The attributes that are mass assignable.
     *
     * @var array
     */
    protected $fillable = [
        'title','content','image', 'phone', 'coordinates', 'website'
    ];

    // this function will give your full image URL in records
    public function getImageAttribute($value)
    {
        return env('APP_URL').$value;
    }
}
```

**And in .env set APP_URL with your domain name of project**
like `https://www.project.com/`

Comment: hello, i got new error after i adding your code: Call to undefined function App\Models\asset() (500 Internal Server Error)

Comment: Updated code. Please check

Comment: thanks for answering, but unfortunately I'm already added domain name on my .env but the result is still the same, you can see it on http://lovemonster.my.id/hospital

Comment: does it any possibility that causing the error?

Comment: Did you change this line in model  return env('APP_URL').$value;
Replace this line and clear cache

Comment: the error above is already solved but there's another error, >Method Illuminate\Support\Str::str_random does not exist. on HospitalController, I already add the import and Str on the code

Comment: im using Lumen (9.1.5) (Laravel Components ^9.21) version anyway

Comment: im already resolved the problem, but i got new problem when i accessing the image after i post the new one, i try to upload the image from the last post request and it showing the alert of 404 not found http://lovemonster.my.id/dAJGaS1zQTSVMcrb0qjhmQ7YZTdLCWa4.jpg, do you know how to solved it?